# Django throw OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: '/proc/52826/task/52826/net'

Tags: python, django, ubuntu

After starting project django throw

```
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: '/proc/52826/task/52826/net'
```

or

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/proc/5390/task/56199'
```

Full trace of OSError:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/alex/projects/project/backend/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 419, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/alex/projects/project/backend/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 413, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/alex/projects/project/backend/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 354, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/home/alex/projects/project/backend/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 61, in execute
    super().execute(*args, **options)
  File "/home/alex/projects/project/backend/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 398, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/alex/projects/project/backend/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 96, in handle
    self.run(**options)
  File "/home/alex/projects/project/backend/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 103, in run
    autoreload.run_with_reloader(self.inner_run, **options)
  File "/home/alex/projects/project/backend/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 638, in run_with_reloader
    start_django(reloader, main_func, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/alex/projects/project/backend/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 623, in start_django
    reloader.run(django_main_thread)
  File "/home/alex/projects/project/backend/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 329, in run
    self.run_loop()
  File "/home/alex/projects/project/backend/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 335, in run_loop
    next(ticker)
  File "/home/alex/projects/project/backend/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 375, in tick
    for filepath, mtime in self.snapshot_files():
  File "/home/alex/projects/project/backend/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 391, in snapshot_files
    for file in self.watched_files():
  File "/home/alex/projects/project/backend/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 294, in watched_files
    yield from directory.glob(pattern)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/pathlib.py", line 1140, in glob
    for p in selector.select_from(self):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/pathlib.py", line 587, in _select_from
    for p in successor_select(starting_point, is_dir, exists, scandir):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/pathlib.py", line 535, in _select_from
    entries = list(scandir_it)
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: '/proc/52826/task/52826/net'
```

Trace of  FileNotFoundError:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/alex/projects/project/backend/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 419, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/alex/projects/project/backend/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 413, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/alex/projects/project/backend/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 354, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/home/alex/projects/project/backend/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 61, in execute
    super().execute(*args, **options)
  File "/home/alex/projects/project/backend/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 398, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/alex/projects/project/backend/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 96, in handle
    self.run(**options)
  File "/home/alex/projects/project/backend/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 103, in run
    autoreload.run_with_reloader(self.inner_run, **options)
  File "/home/alex/projects/project/backend/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 638, in run_with_reloader
    start_django(reloader, main_func, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/alex/projects/project/backend/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 623, in start_django
    reloader.run(django_main_thread)
  File "/home/alex/projects/project/backend/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 329, in run
    self.run_loop()
  File "/home/alex/projects/project/backend/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 335, in run_loop
    next(ticker)
  File "/home/alex/projects/project/backend/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 375, in tick
    for filepath, mtime in self.snapshot_files():
  File "/home/alex/projects/project/backend/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 391, in snapshot_files
    for file in self.watched_files():
  File "/home/alex/projects/project/backend/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 294, in watched_files
    yield from directory.glob(pattern)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/pathlib.py", line 1140, in glob
    for p in selector.select_from(self):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/pathlib.py", line 587, in _select_from
    for p in successor_select(starting_point, is_dir, exists, scandir):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/pathlib.py", line 534, in _select_from
    with scandir(parent_path) as scandir_it:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/proc/5390/task/56199'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a error in django at all.

You have an error in your settings.py at the TEMPLATES config.

It will probably look like this, passing a string.

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
    ...
        "DIRS": "/my/template/path",
    ...
    }
]
```

This is causing the problem, django will iterate over the string were it expects an list. In this example watching the paths: ["/","m","y","/","t","e"...].

The fix is simple, put your path in an list.

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
    ...
        "DIRS": ["/my/template/path"],
    ...
    }
]
```

I will try to get a pull request going that checks if the DIRS parameter is an list.